# AngularJS - {{$index}} within onclick

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm attempting to compile {{$index}} from a ng-repeat inside an onclick. Setup looks like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="stuff in things" >
<a href="#" onclick="superDuperFunction({{$index}});">Foo</a>
</div>
```

Except, I'm getting a console error instead of it {{$index}} compiling.

```
Error: [$compile:nodomevents] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$compile/nodomevents
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular.min.js:6:453
    at pre (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular.min.js:57:54)
    at S (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular.min.js:49:122)
    at h (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular.min.js:43:59)
    at h (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular.min.js:43:76)
    at h (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular.min.js:43:76)
    at h (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular.min.js:43:76)
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular.min.js:42:114
    at http://localhost:3000/lib/angular.min.js:183:186 <a href="#" onclick="superDuperFunction({{$index}});">
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using an inline JS handler when you're using Angular?

Comment: Honestly, I'm still learning the ups and downs of Angular. Just couldn't find proper documentation on a situation like this.

Comment: `ng-click` is definitely the way you want to go, then you define the function in the controller such as `$scope.myFunc = function(param) {`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `<a href="#" ng-click="superDuperFunction($index)">Foo</a>`.

Docs/examples:

- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick
- http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: I thought that at first, but it doesn't seem to work. I attempted to use ng-click with a function that has no parameters does work with onclick, but doesn't work with ng-click.

Comment: Make sure that `superDuperFunction`is defined in your controller i.e. `$scope.superDuperFunction = function(index) { ...`.